# How can I pass JVM system properties on to my tests?

Tags: gradle, geb

I have the following task

```
task testGeb(type:Test) {
   jvmArgs '-Dgeb.driver=firefox'
   include "geb/**/*.class"
   testReportDir = new File(testReportDir, "gebtests")
}
```

The system property doesn't appear to make it to the Geb tests, as Geb does not spawn Firefox to run the tests.  When I set the same system property in Eclipse and run the tests, everything works fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using system properties:

```
test {
   systemProperties['geb.driver'] = 'firefox'
   include "geb/**/*.class"
   testReportDir = new File(testReportDir, "gebtests")
}
```

Comment: This might actually be an issue with Geb.  I confirmed that the prop is being passed properly.

Comment: There was a bug in early snapshot versions of 0.6 that would have prevented this from working, but it has been resolved for the 0.6 final.

Answer (score 7):

You can also directly set the system property in the task:

```
task testGeb(type:Test) {
    System.setProperty('geb.driver', 'firefox')}
```

(the solution above will also work for task type different from `Test`)

or if you would like to be able to pass different properties from the command line, you can include a more flexible solution in the task definition:

```
task testGeb(type:Test) {
    jvmArgs project.gradle.startParameter.systemPropertiesArgs.entrySet().collect{"-D${it.key}=${it.value}"}
}
```

and then you can run:
`./gradlew testGeb -D[anyArg]=[anyValue]`, in your case: `./gradlew testGeb -Dgeb.driver=firefox`

Answer (score 1):

```
Below code works fine for me using Gradle and my cucumber scenarios are passing perfectly. Add below code in your build.gradle file:

//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck

test{

    systemProperties['webdriver.chrome.driver'] = '/usr/bin/google_chrome/chromedriver'

}
```

Note: I used Ubuntu OS and the chrome_driver path I specified in /usr/bin/google_chrome/ and your path varies according to your path.

Answer (score 1):

Add `systemProperties System.getProperties()` in your task

```
test {
  ignoreFailures = false
  include "geb/**/*.class"
  testReportDir = new File(testReportDir, "gebtests")
  // set a system property for the test JVM(s)
  systemProperties System.getProperties()
}
```

So that it will be configurable while running the test. For example

```
gradle -Dgeb.driver=firefox test
gradle -Dgeb.driver=chrome test
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing the following

```
gradle myTask -DmyParameter=123
```

with the following code

```
task myTask {
    doLast {
        println System.properties['myParameter']
    }
 }
```

The output should be

gradle myTask -DmyParameter=123
   :myTask
   123

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.115 secs

Comment: This only sets the property for the Gradle JVM, not the JVM that runs the tests.